How to find out what are all the never allow rules in Selinux policy for a specific Android version?
I want to Extract selinux never allow rules from aosp and compare it with the never allow rules I have in my customized device.
I have tried using sesearch tool for extracting never allow rules from pre-compiled selinux policy in my device but I see no output. I want to get the output of all the never allow rules from android and also the customized device I have to see if there is any tampering of never allow rules in my device; how to do this?
Research paper reference
